# How to filter data in column using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have problem on filtering data from a column in google sheets. It is pushing all the data in a column. However, I just want to push data that contains "MQ"

So far, in the column, it contains data with MQ and Grand total. I just want the data that contain "MQ" to be pushed. Below is the screenshot of the current output
[image: existing output]

```
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var spreadsheetName = activeSpreadSheet.getName(); // Added
      var sheets = activeSpreadSheet.getSheets();
      for (var sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sheets.length; sheetIndex++) {
        var sheet = sheets[sheetIndex];
        var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var resultArr = [];
        for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
          for (var j=24;j<30;j++) {    //j is the column range
            var cellVal = data[i][j];
            if (cellVal > 0) {
              resultArr.push([data[i][17],data[0][j],cellVal]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I expect the output to show the data that only contains "MQ" in the column

Comment: Your script shows no recognizable attempt at filtering items with "MQ"

Comment: Yes because I am not sure how to write the function for filtering the data in a particular column

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the structure of sheet in the image. So if `data[i][17]` is the values including `MQ`, how about modifying from `if (cellVal > 0) {` to `if (cellVal > 0 && ~data[i][17].indexOf("MQ")) {`? If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: @Sriram I would use [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) here; but there are many options. If you want more specific information, you'll need to share a minimal example of your sheet.

Comment: @Tanaike You are a genius. It worked. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. As you can see from @sinaraheneba 's comment, there are several solutions for your situation. So I think that when you post those solutions as an answer, it will be useful for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working solution:

```
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var spreadsheetName = activeSpreadSheet.getName(); // Added
      var sheets = activeSpreadSheet.getSheets();
      for (var sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sheets.length; sheetIndex++) {
        var sheet = sheets[sheetIndex];
        var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var resultArr = [];
        for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
          for (var j=24;j<30;j++) {
            var cellVal = data[i][j];
            if (cellVal > 0 && ~data[i][17].indexOf("MQ")) {
              resultArr.push([data[i][17],data[0][j],cellVal]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```